# C# compiling program into 2 exe files

Tags: c#, .net, compilation

I am writing application in C# using Windows Forms. Sometimes I change settings of my project and set 'Output type' to 'Console Application'.

I wonder is it possible to compile project either as Windows Form Application and as Console Application into 2 .exe files?

Comment: No, that´s not possible as the two projects are completely different. However you can create a form from within a console-app and have a command-line argument indicating that you want the GUI to be opened.

Comment: You can check for some specific executable arguments and use `AllocConsole` to allocate console in case of special flag.

Answer (score 10):

You should put your logic into a dll and create two applications: one console application and one winforms application. That would be the cleanest and in my opinion best way.

So you can deal with the different requierements and handle them in the best way for each of the both application types.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Mighty Badaboom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098337/767890), imagine you are implementing a *Tic Tac Toe* game.

A good design would be to implement all game logic decoupled from the user interface, in its own class library (dll). Inside this class library you could define the basic common behavior any compatible user interface must provide:

```
public interface IUserInterface
{
    void ShowBoard();
    Move GetPlayerMove(Player player);
    void ShowWinnerAnimation(Player player);
    void ShowDrawAnimation();
    ///etc
}
```

And now, you can implement different user interfaces (Console, Web page, Windows Forms, etc.) that you can inject to your `Game` object via the interface:

```
IUserInterface myUserInterface = new WindowsFormsInterface();
var game = new Game(myUserInterface);
game.Run();
```

Comment: Nice example :)